# Java - How to Compare Char[] Array with String?

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

I have a question regarding the comparison of the characters within an Array with a specific input which is a String.

I seem to have a problem at line where it states:  **String[] oneRow = alphabet[i];**

```
package MemoryGame;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Memory {

```
/*
 * array list of the alphabet.
 */

char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

/*
 * Constructor
 */
public Memory(){

    /*
     * Scanner initiation for input end-user.
     */
    System.out.println("What is the first letter of you name? ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String letter = scan.nextLine();
    String s = scan.nextLine();

    /*
     * Comparing Input with array
     */
    String[] matchedRow;
    for(int i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
    {           
        String[] oneRow = alphabet[i];

        if(oneRow[0].equals(letter))
        {
            matchedRow = oneRow;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<matchedRow.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(matchedRow[i]);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Memory memory = new Memory();   
}
```

Eclipse says:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String[]

Thanks for your help!

M

Comment: You have told us you have a problem. Mind describing the problem as well? Error message, anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment of a character to a `String` is invalid. You can use a concatenation trick to do it anyway, but that borders on a hack:

```
String[] oneLetter = ""+alphabet[i];
```

A better approach would be to check that `letter` has the length of `1`, and that its only character matches `alphabet[i]`:

```
if (letter.length() == 1 && letter.charAt(0) == alphabet[i]) {
    matchedLetter = alphabet[i];
    break;
}
```

Comment: @MieerDarwesh Yes, the whole body of the loop gets replaced with this `if` statement. `matchedLetter` needs to be of type `char`, and the loop at the end becomes a single statement. That's an awful lot of work to check if a single letter has been entered, by the way.

Comment: This shows, how important it is, which attributes to consider when writing code to validate those attributes. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a single character to a String array.  You couldn't assign a single String to an array, either; that part has nothing to do with chars.

Of course, you can't assign a char to a String directly, either, so you probably want something like this:

```
String onerow = String.valueOf(alphabet[i]);

if(oneRow.equals(letter))
```

Answer (score -1):

`char` is incompatible with `String` and so `String[]` is not compatible with `char[]`.

`alphabet[i]` will return a `char`, you can transform it into a `String` by constructing a new one, for example:

```
char c = aplhabet[i];
String oneRow = String.valueOf(c);
if (oneRow.equals(letter)) { ... }
```

Or, you can compare the first `char` of the input `String` with the `char` you took from `alphabet`:

```
char c = aplhabet[i];
if (letter.chartAt(0) == c) { ... }
```